# How to call a eclipse plugin developed with Xtext in another plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, xtext

I added Plugin B as dependency in Plugin A. I tried calling the activator of Plugin B in the handler, but it did not work.

Whenever I run Plugin A as eclipse application, in the runtime environment window, I can see the menu button in eclipse that I have created along with default ones, on the click of which Plugin B(which basically gives an editor/IDE environment for a DSL developed with Xtext and is in three parts - Plugin B, Plugin B.tests, Plugin B.ui) should be invoked as an eclipse application in the same runtime environment.

Plugin B does not have any main method in it.

I searched a lot but found the answers only those that were revolving around some method of one plugin to be called 
in the other.

Comment: What does 'invoked as an eclipse application' mean? You can't run a single plugin as an Eclipse application unless it is designed to be an RCP. Do you want to open the editor or something like that?

Comment: The problem with Plugin B is that it is not like 'Calling a method within a plugin from another plugin', it gives the editor window to create the files with extensions defined in the DSL only if it is run as an eclipse application.

Comment: So, when I run Plugin B as an eclipse application, it simply opens a new eclipse where I can create, modify or do whatever I want with the type of files defined in DSL written in Plugin B. The same thing should happen when I click on a button in already running 'Runtime Environment' of Plugin A where Plugin B is listed as dependency.

Comment: Can you please elaborate @greg-449 , I am beginner.

Comment: Running a complete new Eclipse is extremely complex. I don't understand why you can't just open an editor in the current Eclipse.

Comment: That is the requirement of my project.

Comment: So the thing is like, just like when we open a new eclipse, we get everything blank, but if we create a new project in it and restart it, it will fetch the already opened/created projects and will show all of them together i.e. it will not be empty next time I will open it.

Comment: Similarly, my runtime environment of Plugin A will be having some customized menu buttons with one button for invoking the functionality of Plugin B which is described in the previous comment.
If I switch among button in the runtime environment of Plugin A, and come back to click the button for invoking Plugin B, it should behave like a normal eclipse application.

Comment: Well you will either have to build a separate Eclipse RCP containing the Plugin B code and everything it needs and then to launch that RCP using `ProcessBuilder` or use the Eclipse Launch support described in the 'Platform debug and launch support' section of the 'Platform Plug-in Programmers Guide'. Both of these methods are far to complex for a Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: I will try for the keywords you have mentioned. Thanks for your time.